# how to divide actual months to 5 days periods using plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I need  to get first day of each five days of month using posgrees. For example if no is 2.03 then I would get 1.03. If today would be 19.03 then I would get 15.03. I tried to use following if statements but for today;s day I got null and I'm not sure why. Also there surely is some less complicated way to do this operation. Any ideas?

```
create or replace function getFirstDayOfFive()
returns timestamp with time zone as $$
declare
firstDay timestamp;
begin
if (now()::date>date_trunc('month', now()::date) and now()::date < date_trunc('month', now()::date) + interval '5 day') then
    return firstDay = date_trunc('month', now()::date);
elsif (now()::date>date_trunc('month', now()::date) + interval '5 day' and now()::date < date_trunc('month', now()::date) + interval '10 day') then
    return firstDay = (date_trunc('month', now()::date) + interval '5 day')::date;
elsif (now()::date>date_trunc('month', now()::date) + interval '10 day' and now()::date < date_trunc('month', now()::date) + interval '15 day') then
    return firstDay = (date_trunc('month', now()::date) + interval '10 day')::date;
elsif (now()::date>date_trunc('month', now()::date) + interval '15 day' and now()::date < date_trunc('month', now()::date) + interval '20 day') then
    return firstDay = (date_trunc('month', now()::date) + interval '15 day')::date;
elsif (now()::date>date_trunc('month', now()::date) + interval '20 day' and now()::date < date_trunc('month', now()::date) + interval '25 day') then
    return firstDay = (date_trunc('month', now()::date) + interval '20 day')::date;
end if;
end;

$$
language plpgsql;
```

Comment: To clarify: For day 1-4, you want to get day 1 (which is not a multiple of 5!), for 5-9 you expect 5, for 10 to 14 the 10, and so on?

Comment: yes, and then if we have for example 25-28 then I want 25, if there is only 31, I want 31.

Comment: and then I would need to do the same thing in reverse order to get last of five days

Comment: see my solution. For last day you basicly change floor into ceil

Comment: thanks, for last day it gives me an error   date field value out of range: 2021-02-30 if I try to get last day of five in february (should be 25-28 so the answer 28)

Comment: Added a working example to my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ce74c72f465426a06fefac585321f246)

```
SELECT
    make_date(                                             -- 4
        date_part('year', my_date)::int,                   -- 3
        date_part('month', my_date)::int,                     
        greatest(                                          -- 2
            floor(date_part('day', my_date) / 5) * 5,      -- 1
            1
        )::int
    )
```

1. Get day of the current date using `date_part()`. After it round it to full multiple 5 with `floor(day / 5) * 5`
2. The provided algorithm always gives the previous multiple of 5 (for `19` it gives `15`, for `6` it gives `5`, ...). However, for days `1` to `4` it gives `0`. So this is an exception which needs to be handled. This is done here
3. Get year and month part of the current date
4. Create the expected date.

This query can be embedded into a function, of course:

```
create or replace function getFirstDayOfFive()
returns timestamp with time zone as $$
declare
    firstDay timestamp;
begin

SELECT
    make_date(
        date_part('year', now())::int,
        date_part('month', now())::int,
        greatest(
            floor(date_part('day', now()) / 5) * 5,
            1
        )::int
    )
INTO firstDay;

RETURN firstDay;
    
end;

$$
language plpgsql;
```

---

**Edit**: From the comments: Same for Last Day:

You have to change:

1. `floor()` to `ceil()`
2. the `greatest(..., 1)` into `least(..., last day of current month)`

To get the last date of the current month, you have to find the first day using `date_trunc('month', ...)`, add one month to get the first day of the next month and subtract one day from it:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=d4597997701ab9cabd0b42628f822371)

```
SELECT
    least(
        ceil(date_part('day', now()) / 5) * 5,
        date_part('day', date_trunc('month', now()) + interval '1 month - 1 day')
    )
```

Comment: Actually I was trying the same just instead of the 2 line of least I was using my function and there was some casting error that timestamp cannod be used in leasy. THANKS!